# Есть ли возможность переводить координаты объекта в глобальные координаты страницы при плавном перемещении карты?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

При открытии балуна на объекте в ObjectManager происходит плавное перемещение к метке и открытие балуна. Необходимо вычислять координаты метки относительно документа, для перерисовки линии в канвасе. Но пока не закончится перемещение, возвращаются одинаковые координаты

```js
map.mapsetCenter(
    [parseFloat(this.dataset.lat), parseFloat(this.dataset.lng)], 
    map.getZoom(), 
    {duration: 500}
);

for (var k = 0; k < 500; k = k + 50) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var position = map.converter.globalToPage(
            map.options.get('projection').toGlobalPixels(
                coords,
                map.getZoom()
            )
        );
        console.log(position);
    }, 10);
}
```

10 раз вернет одинаковые координаты, а необходимо текущее положение элемента относительно страницы

Может есть какое-то событие (между balloonautopanbegin и balloonautopanend, actiontick на карте тоже пробывал), которое позволит корректно пересчитывать координаты